# How does Javascript's native sort method work?

Tags: javascript, sorting, mergesort

```
[1, false, 10, "b", 3, "33", ":", "R", "^"].sort()
```

Yields the following sort:

```
[1, 10, 3, "33", ":", "R", "^", "b", false]
```

Can anyone explain how the sort method works? I'm guessing that it must be translating everything into ASCII.

The plot thickens when I do this

```
[1, false, 10, "b", 3, "33", ":", "R", "^"].sort(function(a,b) {return b-a})
```

Outputs the following:

```
[10, 1, false, "b", "33", 3, ":", "R", "^"]
```

Any method to this madness?

Comment: The default sort order is according to string Unicode code points.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Why can't you add some info on why you think it looks like madness e.g. show that it's not what you'd have thought it was

Comment: Totally. String unicode makes sense, but I thought that the native .sort and the sort(fn (a,b,) {return b-a}) would return the same order. Instead, the order is not even flipped in the second example. It is rearranged with regards to 10,1, and false.

Answer (score 6):

From MDN:

> If compareFunction is not supplied, elements are sorted by converting them to strings and comparing strings in Unicode code point order.

And:

> If compareFunction is supplied, the array elements are sorted according to the return value of the compare function.

Ref:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort